# Aptana - Keyboard shortcut for HTML/JS (jQuery) Preview within the IDE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

Is there an Aptana shortcut button for previewing within the IDE? (rather than having to mouse over to IE) ...

Comment: surely there must be a shorcut button to preview the page inside the ide..

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard shortcut for switch between source/preview:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PgDwn</kbd>

*Not mentioned in official documentation.*