# Where does Eclipse store keyboard bindings?

Tags: eclipse

Where does Eclipse store its user preferences? Specifically the keyboard bindings?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462216/aptana-keyboard-shortcut-for-html-js-jquery-preview-within-the-ide (unanswered)

Comment: I think thw OP is asking where the settings themselves are stored ie. in `~/.eclipse`, `$project_path/.settings` etc..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you close Eclipse, any local settings regarding key shortcuts (settings that differ from the default configuration) are saved in

```
</path/to/workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
```

Comment: I will never understand why this kind of settings are stored in the workspace instead of it being IDE-wide

Comment: @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin I have touched Eclipse recently (thanks VSCode). Does Eclipse still does that eleven years later?

Comment: I was looking for this info to know if it would be worth it to re-bind my Eclipse keyboard shortcuts to those of IntelliJ (I maintain a couple legacy projects that require Eclipse). That file you described still exists and judging by the fact that it still doesn't keep even the theme between workspaces, it's safe to assume that yes. Shortcuts are probably still stored there 11 years later

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just copy the whole line in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbech.prefs` file that starts with: `org.eclipse.ui.commands=`
and paste it into the other corresponding eclipse workspace prefs file you want to update - at least in Eclipse Neon, and you'll get them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the bindings using the following groovy script. I'm not a groovy developer so please excuse my hack.

Groovy Script Used (substitute in a correct path to the workbench xmi file):

```
workbench = new XmlSlurper().parse("<path to  eclipse>/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi")

List bindingTables
workbench.bindingTables.each
{ it->
//println "\tContributorURI: ${it.@contributorURI} | \tElementID : it.@elementId";

def command = "command";
def commandName = "commandname";
def description = "description";
def category;
def name = "name";
def keys = "keys";
it.bindings.each
{bindingIt->
    //loop through every binding entry
    command = bindingIt.@command;
    keys = bindingIt.@keySequence;
    workbench.commands.each
    {commandIt->
        def thisCommand = commandIt.attributes()['{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id'];
        if(thisCommand.equals(command.toString()) )
        {
            commandName = commandIt.@commandName;
            description = commandIt.@description;
            category = commandIt.@category;
            workbench.categories.each
            {workbenchIt->
                if(workbenchIt.attributes()['{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id'].equals(category.toString()) )
                {
                    name = workbenchIt.@name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println "\t\tKeys: ${keys}\tCommand: ${commandName}"+
            "\tDescription: "+description+"\tName: "+name;
}
}
```