# Key binding shows shortcut list pop up even when only one option in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings, eclipse-juno

I installed  Eclipse Juno and key binding does not seems to be working well. I mean, I did add a couple of key bindings.

```
Ctrl+B Build in Windows
Shift+Ctrl+B Build All in Windows
Shift+Alt+B Toggle Breakpoint in Debugging
```

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> the typical pop up with both `Build All` and `Build` appears.

When swapping `Build` and `Build All` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> does show the pop up with only one option (`Build All`).

Where are those bindings stored, so I can overwrite them directly?

Comment: This is so annoying! Eclipse :(

Comment: I can also confirm I am annoyed about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Where does Eclipse store keyboard bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471234/where-does-eclipse-store-keyboard-bindings)

You'll find where your bindings are stored at the above link. If you browse through the file indicated you should recognize your keybindings. What I found were a bunch of duplicate entries. Back up your file, so you don't screw yourself, and carefully edit out the duplicates--observe the pattern of the working keybindings. After this, I found that from the key editor inside eclipse it was still showing bindings that shouldn't be there (probably some type of caching mechanism). I removed these bindings through the editor, restarted, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem creating a new workspace and importing the projects all over again.

*Not a nice solution but worked. FINALLY.*